# Entanglement-assisted communication ability of a quantum depolarizing channel vs. a classical binary symmetric channel

Tags: information-theory, communication, nonclassicality, depolarizing-channel

Consider  a quantum qubit depolarizing channel which takes a quantum state $\rho$ to output

$$N(\rho) = (1-p)\rho + p\frac{\mathbb{1}_2}{2}.$$

If I restrict $\rho$ to be either $\vert0\rangle\langle 0\vert$ or $\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert$, then the depolarizing channel outputs

$$N(\vert0\rangle\langle 0\vert) = (1-\frac{p}{2})\vert0\rangle\langle 0\vert + \frac{p}{2}\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert$$
$$N(\vert1\rangle\langle 1\vert) = (1-\frac{p}{2})\vert1\rangle\langle 1\vert + \frac{p}{2}\vert 0\rangle\langle 0\vert.$$

That looks like a binary symmetric channel with crossover probability $\frac{p}{2}$.

I am free to restrict $\rho$ to be a classical superposition i.e. of the form $q\vert0\rangle\langle 0\vert + (1-q)\vert 1\rangle\langle 1\vert$, then it is clear that I still obtain the same results as a binary symmetric channel.

Is there a communication task where the quantum depolarizing channel is a more powerful resource than a classical BSC? I understand one can do say, entanglement distribution with one but not the other so to make the playing field even, I allow unlimited pre-shared entanglement between Alice and Bob.

Now, I would like to know if Alice and Bob who share depolarizing channels can actually use it to send more information than if they just had a classical BSC.

Comment: well, with the quantum channel you can send over *quantum states*, which you clearly cannot in the classical case. Or if you're referring specifically to classical communication tasks, being allowed pre-shared entanglement, you can send over classical information at a rate given by the entanglement-assisted classical capacity, which is higher in general than the standard classical capacity

Comment: Is the maximum of the quantum mutual information (entanglement-assisted classical capacity) of a depolarizing channel with depolarizing probability $p$ larger than the maximum of the classical mutual information (classical capacity) of a BSC with crossover probability $p/2$? Note also that the latter case doesn't utilize the entanglement assistance so I'm not sure if that's even the right things to compare

Comment: Additionally, @gIS, I guess you meant to say this but just clarifying that you can send a quantum state over the BSC when you have free shared entanglement. You just do teleportation.

Comment: mh, maybe I misunderstood. Which one is allowed to use pre-shared entanglement here? Only the classical channel or both? I feel like if the "classical channel" is allowed to use pre-shared entanglement, then it's the same as the quantum channel when used to send classical info. That is, they will fair exactly the same for any such task. Whereas in terms of quantum capacities, you inquire about rate of just sending states through the channel, vs rate at which one can sent states with a classical channel with entanglement via teleportation. That's an interesting question

Comment: Both are allowed to use pre-shared entanglement. Case 1) Alice and Bob have pre-shared entanglement + a classical BSC with crossover probability $p/2$. Case 2) Alice and Bob have pre-shared entanglement and a quantum depolarizing channel with depolarizing probability $p$. I would like to know if these are non-equivalent for any communication task (either classical or quantum).